# fb:explicitly_shared=true not working

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-opengraph

```
FB.api("me/bookvote:download", "post", {
    book: "http://mysite/auction_details.php?name='.$item_details["name"].'&auction_id='.$item_details["auction_id"].'&fb:explicitly_shared=true",

}, //Missing a , here?
```

code is above, I am trying to use the url parameter fb:explicitly_shared=true but it is only showing up on my activity feed, how to properly post the data?

I have also tried this with no luck

```
FB.api("me/bookvote:download", "post", {
    book: "http://mysite/auction_details.php?name='.$item_details["name"].'&auction_id='.$item_details["auction_id"].'",
fb:explicitly_shared="true"  
}, //Missing a , here?
```

Comment: good that u found out! might help someone someday :)

Comment: If you solve the question yourself please post the solution as an answer. Do not edit the question out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

In your object there is a mistake.

Because `:` seperates key from value you've to put fb:explicitly_shared into `'` or `"` to get the whole string as key.

Try this one:

```
FB.api("me/bookvote:download", "post", {
  'fb:explicitly_shared' : 'true'  
}
```